# C++ Initialize vector with another vector

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Consider the class `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int);
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() = default;
    Bar(const std::vector<int> & v);

private:
    std::vector<Foo> data_;
};
```

How to write the constructor `Bar(const std::vector<int> & v)` so that each element of `v` can initialize a `Foo` object with `Foo(int)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
Bar(const std::vector<int> & v) : data_(v.begin(), v.end()) {}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the copy ctor here?

Comment: @scohe001, yes. We are creating a `vector<Foo>` from a `vector<int>`.

Comment: Ahh makes sense, I glazed over that. Thanks!